# NX9105 Wireless not working

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers

I am using my old hp-compaq NX9105 laptop. I installed 12.04 and upgraded to 14.04.

Problem is that wireless is not working. No wireless is detected. I installed the b43 driver as described [here](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/b43-dev/2013-October/003262.html), but no luck.

Please, any ideas? A step-by-step walkthrough would be great!

Here is the output of running  `lspci -vnn | grep Network`

```
 02:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 03)
```

Comment: Please post the output of running `lspci -vnn | grep Network` in terminal.  to open terminal press <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<T>

Comment: (@KasiyA) george@george-hp-compaq-nx9105-PG691EA-B1A:~$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
02:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 03)

Comment: I installed the b43 driver as shown here: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43. But, following the instructions it shows that my system uses wl driver, not the one I downloaded. I can't put wl in blacklist. Am I in the right path?

Comment: SOLVED. I followed this guide and it worked! Thanks! https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access

Answer (score 0):

just run following command in terminal one by one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo reboot
```

<sub>cuted from [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)</sub>